# derivate discounted payoff

Tags: derivatives, expected-value, conditional-expectation, finance

Let $S(t)$ be the stock price at time $t\geq 0$ with $S(0)=s_0$ and let $\Pi(S_t)=\max\{K-S_t,0\}=(K-S_t)_+$ the payoff of an american put with strike price $K$. How can I calculate the derivate $\frac{d}{d \psi} \mathbb E[e^{-\delta t} \Pi(S(t))\chi_{\{S(t)<\psi\}} | S(0)=s]$ for a stochastic $t$ and fixed $s$? I dont know how to start here, thanks for a hint.

Answer (score 1):

I'd reason like this:

first we can notice that in order for the argument to be different to zero, i must be that both $S < K$ and $S < \psi$. Hence we have two cases:

1. $\psi > K$: in this case it must be $S< K$ and then the function does not depend on $\psi$ which means its derivative is zero
2. $\psi < K$: in this case it must be $S< \psi$ and then the expectation becomes

$$
A:= \int_{-\infty}^{\psi}e^{-\delta t}(K-S)f_S(S) dS \Rightarrow A_{\psi} = e^{-\delta t}(K-\psi)f_S(\psi)
$$

Putting both together, I'd say the derivative is $ e^{-\delta t}(K-\psi)^{\text{+}}f_S(\psi)$

Comment: You oversimplified the problem by considering a European option instead of an American. Also: OP asked for the derivative of the price, not of the payoff.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I didn't pay too much attention to the details (European vs America) because I focused on the expectation he wrote. That expectation seems to me the one for an European option. the price for the american one would involve a min/max and the time would be stochastic as well. As for the price part, by taking the derivative of the integral and including the density function, I'd say that is in fact the price and not the payoff. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are correct. An answer can only be as good as the question and this one should be closed, unless OP comes back and clarifies things.

Comment: @finch the time is also stochastic, so wie have the derivative of the expectation of a discounted american put. I corrected it.